# AWS new generation (m3.x) Intstance configuration not suppported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I am using java sdk to create ec2 instances. 
Till now I was using m1.medium, m1.large, m1.xlarge configuration to create ec2 instance and it was successfully creating the ec2 instance. 
But when i changed the instance type to new generation (m3.medium, m3.large, m3.xlarge), i am getting the below error.

Message : The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported. Please see http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=5hoheke3dcdw953i7sq087tpb for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems.

NOTE: I am getting this error only in AWS US West 2 (ie Oregon) region. I am able to create m3.x instances in other region successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that AMI is an Ubuntu 12.04 image that I don't believe is supported on the new generation instances. We've run into a similar issue, we've had to move to Ubuntu 14.04 which does support PV virtualization. Based on this article it does not appear that one AMI image can run on all instance types:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ec2ubuntu/XdyrnPnxYAo

I believe this Ubuntu 12.04 LTS image will run on the new generation instance types:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00JOW8C7S/ref=sp_mpg_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2

Comment: I checked both Ubuntu 12.04 LTS AMIs on my own EC2 account in Oregon - one is a PV virtual machine the other is an HVM. They cannot both run on all instance types. According to Ben Howard of Canonical: "At this time, it is not possible to register one AMI for all instance types. The reason is that the paravirtualized instances boot via one method, while the HVM instances boot using Grub2. Until Amazon allows for a single registration, you won't be able to do boot one AMI on all instances."

Comment: Hi John, yes you are right. I had been using the different AMI in AWS Management Console.